# PySpark error An error occurred while calling count caused by null pointer

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm getting `An error occurred while calling o19972810.count` while counting data that i get from JDBC:

```
sql_query = "SELECT.... FROM.... " 
df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", con_mysql_source) \
        .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", f"({sql_query})" sdtable") \
        .option("user", ...).option("password", ...).load()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_temp")

counts = df.count()
```

Here is the full log:

```
aRise Py4JJavaError(\\\\npy4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o19972810.count. : 
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:\\\\nExchange SinglePartition, ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#38969584]
    - *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_count(1)], output=[count#49033654L])
       +- *(1) Scan JDBCRelation((SELECT updatedate,DATE_FORMAT(transaction_tgl, '%Y%m%d') as partdate, user, outlet transaction_tgl , id, status FROM Transactions WHERE updateDate \\u003e '2022-11-29 20:22:23' AND updateDate\\u003c='2022-11-29 20:27:28' AND transaction_tgl \\u003e '1970-01-01 00:00:00' ) sdtable) [numPartitions=1] [] PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct\\u003c\\u003e\
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDD(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:525)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputRDDCodegen.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputRDDCodegen.inputRDDs$(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.HashAggregateExec.inputRDDs(HashAggregateExec.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:746)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:387)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$count$1(Dataset.scala:3019)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$count$1$adapted(Dataset.scala:3018)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3700)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3698)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:3018)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Python Version : 3.7

Spark : 3.1.3

mysql driver :  mysql-connector-java-8.0.29

The weird thing is that this error is solved by restarting the VM and it rarely happens, like once a month or once every 2 weeks. We have no clue why it happens since we've crosschecked our database and we certain that the selected column has no null value.

Because of that we're having difficulties reproducing it both in local & staging.

### Any help / idea are appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Update:

Later we found that before this error is produced, we found another error that state `GC overhead limit exceeded` and `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 180601 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down` then Kibana show the `count error`.

Is it related & possible produce such error if we trigger the our spark frequently after previous job is finished?

Comment: Does your full error stack trace also contain some lines under `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`, which is the last line you printed in your question? If yes, could you add those lines too?

Comment: @Koedlt unfortunately, this is the only error we got from kibana...